# VideoReader Matlab: Avi movie clip fps, length and number of frames don't match

Tags: matlab, video-processing, codec, avi

I have a short 2 minute video and I use the following code to get it's specs:

```
vidObj = VideoReader('./Clip1.avi');

vidHeight = vidObj.Height;
vidWidth = vidObj.Width;
```

and then with

```
vidObj.Duration = 121.25
```

but when I want to get the number of frames and frame rate (fps), I get the following:

```
vidObj.FrameRate = 24
vidObj.NumberOfFrames = 2112
```

and 2112/24 is **88 seconds**, but the specs just said the video Duration has **121.25 seconds**. What is going wrong on how Matlab is loading the video? Am I missing a codec?

I'm running this on Ubuntu 12.04

For me this is kind of a big deal, since I want to write an automated script that partitions each 2 minute clip into 5 second mini-clips sharp, one after the other. Maybe there's a workaround?

Other clip specs:

```
         Filename: '/home/arturo/Documents/Clip1.avi'
          FileSize: 35519488
       FileModDate: '20-Feb-2015 11:16:29'
         NumFrames: 2910
   FramesPerSecond: 24
             Width: 1024
            Height: 760
         ImageType: 'truecolor'
  VideoCompression: 'XVID'
           Quality: 4.2950e+07
NumColormapEntries: 0
```

**Update:** for some reason on Windows, it can fetch all the 2910 frames.

**Update 2:**

Output of **get(vidObj)**:

```
General Settings:
Duration = 121.2500
Name = 12.5highT1nwloc1V2.avi
Path = /home/arturo/Documents/UAV_Project/Clips/High_Clutter
Tag = 
Type = VideoReader
UserData = []

Video Settings:
BitsPerPixel = 24
FrameRate = 24
Height = 760
NumberOfFrames = 2112
VideoFormat = RGB24
Width = 1024
```

Output of aviinfo('./Clip1.avi'):

```
         Filename: '/home/arturo/Documents/Clip1.avi'
          FileSize: 35519488
       FileModDate: '20-Feb-2015 11:16:29'
         NumFrames: 2910
   FramesPerSecond: 24
             Width: 1024
            Height: 760
         ImageType: 'truecolor'
  VideoCompression: 'XVID'
           Quality: 4.2950e+07
NumColormapEntries: 0
```

Diagnostic: I guess it's probably a Matlab(2012a) for Linux(12.04) bug?

Comment: What happens when you do `get(vidObj);` in the MATLAB command prompt?  Can you show us that information?

Comment: It may be a bug with the Linux distribution of MATLAB or the codec itself.  Perhaps you can find the number of frames by doing `vidObj.Duration*vidObj.FrameRate`.

Comment: Hi everyone, please see updates on original question.